# Lookup pivot field doesn't return correctly

Tags: excel, vba, powerquery

Need help to look up field of pivot table in sheet "A", to match value in another sheet "B" to return the value in the next to the pivot in Sheet "A" .

The problem there's value that can't be find in "B" sheet so when its pasted over it doesn't match the row number ?

```
Set wbSite = ThisWorkbook
Set wsSite = wbSite.Worksheets("test")
Set critSite = wsSite.Range("B14:B10000")
TempArray = critSite
myArray = Application.Transpose(TempArray)

Set wbSource = Workbooks.Open("c:\temp\EmployeeReport.xlsx", , True)
Set wsSource = wbSource.Worksheets("Report 1")
wsSource.Range("A:BL").AutoFilter field:=3, Criteria1:=myArray, Operator:=xlFilterValues

Set wbDest = ThisWorkbook
Set wsDest = wbDest.Worksheets("test")
wsDest.Application.CutCopyMode = False

Set rng1 = Range(("L1:L" & Cells(Rows.Count, "L").End(xlDown).Row)).Cells
rng1.Copy
wsDest.Cells(13, 10).PasteSpecial
   
Set rng1 = Range(("M1:M" & Cells(Rows.Count, "M").End(xlUp).Row)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
rng1.Copy
wsDest.Cells(13, 11).PasteSpecial
```

Sheet A

| ID | Name |
| --- | --- |
| 01 | Albert |
| 02 | John |
| 03 | Michael |
| 04 | Tony |
| 05 | Robert |

Sheet B

| ID | Car Registration |
| --- | --- |
| 01 | H657545 |
| 02 | H347545 |
| 05 | H557545 |

Expected Result

| ID | Name | Car Registration) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 01 | Albert | H657545 |
| 02 | John | H347545 |
| 03 | Michael | (null) |
| 04 | Tony | (null) |
| 05 | Robert | H557545 |

What happened

| ID | Name | Car Registration) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 01 | Albert | H657545 |
| 02 | John | H347545 |
| 03 | Michael | H557545 |
| 04 | Tony | No Data |
| 05 | Robert | No Data |

Answer (score 1):

Although it's possible in vba I recommend you use powerQuery for this task. Also when manipulating data pivots are not ideal, it's better to directly use the source of the pivot:

1. Open the xls in which you want the output;
2. Go to menu: Data > Get Data > from file > from workbook;
3. choose the "employeeReport.xlsx" file;
4. Select sheet 1 and choose "Transform";

Excel will open Powerquery for you.
Go to the menu Home > Advanced editor.
copy the path and remove all the code.
Paste this instead (Replace the path to your file):

```
    let
        PathToFile = "C:\Dropbox\@Scripts\tests\PowerBI\EmployeeReport.xlsx", //add the full path to your sourcefile. I assume data is in sheet 1 and 2
        Sheet1 = 
            let
                Source = Excel.Workbook(File.Contents(PathToFile), null, true),
                Sheet1_Sheet = Source{[Item="Sheet1",Kind="Sheet"]}[Data],
                #"Promoted Headers" = Table.PromoteHeaders(Sheet1_Sheet, [PromoteAllScalars=true])
            in
                #"Promoted Headers",
        
        Sheet2 =
            let
                Source = Excel.Workbook(File.Contents(PathToFile), null, true),
                Sheet2_Sheet = Source{[Item="Sheet2",Kind="Sheet"]}[Data],
                #"Promoted Headers" = Table.PromoteHeaders(Sheet2_Sheet, [PromoteAllScalars=true])
            in
                #"Promoted Headers",
        
        
        #"Merged Queries" = Table.NestedJoin(Sheet1, {"ID"}, Sheet2, {"ID"}, "Sheet2", JoinKind.LeftOuter),
        #"Expanded Sheet2" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Merged Queries", "Sheet2", {"Car Registration"}, {"Car Registration"})
    in
        #"Expanded Sheet2"
```

Choose "done"
click on "close and load to"
choose table, select where you want your table, hit ok.

As mentioned above it's better to use the source of your pivot, not the pivot so if you need additional logic (grouping, filter, ... ) we can add it to the query instead of using the pivot.

let me know how this works out for you.